# php isset working differently on php 5.3

Tags: php

I have simplified this code down but find that it works differently old versions of php.

```
$data = '1';

if(isset($data['yes'])){
    die('yes');
} else {
    die('no');
}
```

Testing using windows php version 5.4 and linux 5.3

If I change `$data  = 1;` then both work the same. Looking at the manual string offsets has been changed so maybe this has fixed the issue.

So question is how best to build code which works on old versions?

From a performance view which is faster:

```
if(is_array($data) && isset($data['yes'])){

if(array_key_exists('yes', $data)){
```

Comment: If it's an integer, does it need quotes?

Comment: No this just causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most optimal way

```
if (is_array($data) && isset($data['yes']))
{

}
```

If you do `array_key_exists` without checking if `$data` is array, you will get error, because second parameter for the `array_key_exists` function must always be type of `array`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

Second Parameter or array_key_exists must be an array so first option is the best.

```
if(is_array($data) && isset($data['yes'])){}
```

Comment: how's your answer different than George?

Comment: Yes same solution. I've not checked that while giving answers.